# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'opdrachten.OpdrachtID' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this query I get an error message but I dont know what Im doing wrong.

```
SELECT deelnemers.StudentenID, voorkeur.VoorkeurID, 
        opdrachten.OpdrachtID, voorkeur.Voorkeur 
FROM deelnemers 
    INNER JOIN voorkeur, opdrachten ON voorkeur.StudentenID=deelnemers.StudentenID 
WHERE VoorkeurID=1 
AND voorkeur.Voorkeur=opdrachten.OpdrachtID
```

This is query is inserted in an table. Using PHP but when I tried running the query with SQLyog but still the same problem. I also checked multiple times if the column exists and yes it does

Comment: you are not joining `opdrachten` table in your JOINs

Comment: in your query there is not tablename opdrachten - then why you use this in where clause

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I joined the table opdracht and then I get this problem: ` Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON voorkeur.StudentenID = deelnemers.StudentenID 
WHERE VoorkeurID=1 AND voorke' at line 2
`

Comment: @Laurence give complete query which you trying. You may update the question, with this new query

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have edited my query

Comment: `INNER JOIN voorkeur, opdrachten` is invalid SQL it looks like you are trying to mix the old comma join syntax with the newer INNER JOIN syntax.

Comment: Don't use the comma joins. `INNER JOIN voorkeur on ... inner join opdrachten  on ...`.

Comment: Please see the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) for the correct syntax for JOINs.

Comment: @Laurence Please read about [Join Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). You dont **JOIN** tables using comma. You may also check this [simpler tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx).

Comment: Relevant passage from the manual: `However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than that of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.`

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT deelnemers.StudentenID, voorkeur.VoorkeurID, opdrachten.OpdrachtID, 
voorkeur.Voorkeur FROM deelnemers 
INNER JOIN voorkeur ON voorkeur.StudentenID = deelnemers.StudentenID  INNER JOIN 
opdrachten 
ON voorkeur.StudentenID = deelnemers.StudentenID 
WHERE VoorkeurID=1 AND voorkeur.Voorkeur = opdrachten.OpdrachtID
```

This was the what I used and Now I got what I want